# Blur videostream regions in JAVA

Tags: java, video-streaming, video-processing

I am looking for a way to offer a live videostream through a website, but with the idea that certain area's on the videostream are either blurred or pixelated. Because this will be for a competition based setup, it is important that the manipulation is done on the server side and not on the client side. Can anyone recommend me what the best practice is on this, because i have been playing around with ffmpeg but haven't made any progress so far.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) with a gaussian filter.

Doing this for only a small region would be pretty fast, so you should still be able to achieve good framerates.

[Here's a page with a bunch of examples.](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/blurring.html)

Some previous questions on SO:

- [How do I blur an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589760/how-do-i-blur-an-image)
- [Fastest Gaussian blur implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98359/fastest-gaussian-blur-implementation)