# how to apply a filter to an imageView

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have an imageView and want to apply a filter so that it becomes blurred, I use android studio and the version min of sdk is 17, help me to achieve this task

Comment: what type of filter you are looking for ?? Do you tried with wrap content and fitxy ?

Comment: Use ColorMatrices, for fast filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Picasso - Square](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library

And apply the [Picasso Blur Transformation](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1372)

This is easier than trying to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `setAlpha()` method.

Like `imageView.setAlpha(floatValue);`

"floatValue" ranges from 0 to 1.

Try values below 1 for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Read about/Google "Convolution Filters", it's a method of changing a pixels value based on the values of pixels around it. So apart from blurring, you can also do image sharpening and line-finding.

[How do I blur an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589760/how-do-i-blur-an-image)

If your question is how to blur so you can use that

```
imageview = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageview.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
Bitmap blurred = blurRenderScript(bitmap, radiusArr[position]);//second parametre is radius
imageview.setImageBitmap(blurred);
```

for more reference you can refer this url
https://github.com/Cutta/Simple-Image-Blur