# Is it possible to design this view in android xml?

Tags: android, xml, image, view, header

I'm only interested in the header that contains the product image. I am thinking possible ways to make this design but I do not find the possible way to see the whole image blurred except the central circle that looks normal.

[image]

Comment: is the center circle interact with any code or is it just static ?

Comment: This has little to do with Android - there's no built-in method, so you want to take a copy of the centre part of the image (make a circular mask, or whatever), blur the whole image then paste the unmodified circle back in.

Comment: @SígvardrÓlavrsson The circle not has intereaction, but the background image is dynamic, this change because this view is the editable profile of a product.

Comment: @KenY-N Maybe I could cut the circle programmatically and then paste it in the foreground of the blurred image, this is your suggestion? And no, this is not the same question that you have linked, thanks.

Comment: No, it's not an exact dup, but combine it with, for example, [this circular clipping example](http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2012/09/crop-image-in-circular-shape-in-android.html) and make the page background the blurred image, and you're 90% of the way there. (I've decided to withdraw my [dup close vote](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1589760/1270789) - I think there's enough information now for someone to make an answer.)

Comment: @KenY-N Thank you very much, my mind was stuck in trying to do this only using xml but now I have other ways to explore. If I can do this I will post the solution here, thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi, Read this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19947835/5241603

Comment: @K.Sopheak thank you very much, I think this is just what I needed.